# Stop fancyBox from refreshing whole wrapper

Tags: jquery, fancybox

Basically I am trying to create a sort of product image gallery lightbox thing.

Now fancyBox is the closest thing I got to that fits the lightboxes you see on sites like Amazon and buy.com (i.e. http://www.buy.com/prod/norton-360-premier-1-user-3-pcs/240575091.html ) so I thought I would give it a try.

Now you know what I am roughly trying to do.

So I started editing the thumbs helper for fancyBox and I thought I was close when I got the thumbs div to append to `fancybox-outer` instead of `body` however fancyBox seems to want to refresh the whole wrapper it is contained in which means the thumbs pane, of course, disappears and I am left with only the image.

Is there a hack of options I could use to stop the fancyBox from refreshing it's entire self and only refresh it's inner wrapper so I can append the thumbs row to the inside of the dialog?

I have looked through: http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#useful but couldn't see anything immediately.

Comment: If you are hacking the original js files (which is a bad idea in my opinion) why you don't append the thumbs to `fancybox-overlay` instead of the `fancybox-outer`?

Comment: @JFK If I append them to the overlay (I am editing the js file for the thumb helper) they appear outside of the dialog on the darkened background, though maybe there is some CSS tricks I can do to make it look like it isn't, hmmm

Comment: Have you considered creating a new page for the fancybox content, and then loading it into the fancybox as an iframe?  I've done this quite a lot and it works great.

Comment: @markpsmith Doesn't that mean I have to create the gallery myself though and have it loaded in as a AJAX source using fancybox only as a modal? So I lose pretty much all functionality of fancybox except for the modal part.

Comment: yes you're right, that would just create more work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kept tweaking with fancyBox but it just couldn't do what I wanted it to so in the end I gaved up on it.

I, instead, decided to take a couple of days out to build my own: https://github.com/Sammaye/prodigal

It is quite simple and focused on producing an Amazon type product gallery however it does work and I have tested it on:

- Firefox (latest)
- IE (7 and above)
- Safari 5.1 and above
- Opera 12 and above
- and Chrome (latest)

And it works on all of them being able to handle both images and videos.

Feel free to use it, abuse it and just mould it to what you want.