# Lightbox gallery with image and video support

Tags: jquery

I recently looked at fancybox ( [Stop fancyBox from refreshing whole wrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13648768/stop-fancybox-from-refreshing-whole-wrapper) ).

I am unsure as to whether it meets my needs whereby I wanted to change the way the thumbnailer worked to make it inside of the dialog, like on Amazon ( http://www.amazon.co.uk/Assassins-Creed-3-PC-DVD/dp/B007BLPPYW/ref=sr_1_cc_1?s=aps&ie=UTF8&qid=1354523424&sr=1-1-catcorr ) and buy.com ( http://www.buy.com/prod/norton-360-premier-1-user-3-pcs/240575091.html ) when you click on the product images.

I have gone over a considerable amount of the internet looking for something similar however, the most I get is singular lightboxes that work by zooming the image on page.

Even though I could edit fancybox to do roughly what I want I am wondering if anyone here knows of another lightbox which fits my needs better?

#### Edit

I did look at: [prettyPhoto](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/#prettyPhoto[pp_gal]/3/) however there is no example of it's thumbnailer being used with flash and by the position of the thumbnailer (on top of media) in their examples I know it will not work on older flash versions and browsers (as late as IE8) and it will not be so good for YouTube video either (due to ad display etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kept tweaking with fancyBox but it just couldn't do what I wanted it to so in the end I gaved up on it.

I, instead, decided to take a couple of days out to build my own: https://github.com/Sammaye/prodigal

It is quite simple and focused on producing an Amazon type product gallery however it does work and I have tested it on:

- Firefox (latest)
- IE (7 and above)
- Safari 5.1 and above
- Opera 12 and above
- and Chrome (latest)

And it works on all of them being able to handle both images and videos.

Feel free to use it, abuse it and just mould it to what you want.